# spaCy entity ruler not detecting new patterns

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to add some patterns to the entity ruler of spaCy to have it recognize different entities I want from a text file. When I add the patterns the new ruler does not detect them.

This is my current code:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", before = "ner")
```

```
patterns = [
    {"label": "TECH_NAME", "pattern": [{"ENT_TYPE": "PERSON"}]}, 
    {"label": "DATE", "pattern": [{"ENT_TYPE": "DATE"}]},
    {"label": "RUN_TIME", "pattern": [{"LIKE_NUM": True}, {"LOWER": "hour"}, {"LOWER": "hours"}, {"LOWER": "hr"}]},
    {"label": "RUN_TIME", "pattern": [{"LIKE_NUM": True}, {"LOWER": "minute"}, {"LOWER": "minutes"}, {"LOWER": "min"}]},
    {"label": "INSTRUMENT", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "sysmex xn-3000"}, {"LOWER": "roche cobas e411"}]},  
    {"label": "TEST_NAME", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "complete blood count (cbc)"}, {"LOWER": "white blood count (wbc)"}, {"LOWER": "hemoglobin (hb)"}, {"LOWER": "platelet count"}, {"LOWER": "glucose panel"}, {"LOWER": "creatinine"}, {"LOWER": "alt (alanine aminotransferase)"}, {"LOWER": "igg"}, {"LOWER": "pcr test for covid-19"}, {"LOWER": "vitamin d level"}]}
    
    ]
```

```
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)


doc = nlp(text)

for ent in doc.ents:
  print (ent.text, ent.label_)
```

This is the current output where the rules do not seem to be working:

John Doe
DOB PERSON
1980-05-15
Test Date DATE
2023-01-20 DATE
CBC ORG